# How do I configure file associations for IntelliJ on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use the Play framework with IntelliJ community edition, which doesn't know what to do with YAML files. It asked me how to open them, and I chose to use the "associated application". But now whenever I double-click on a YAML file in IntelliJ, nothing happens.

The file associations for YAML files are set correctly in my desktop environment, KDE, and opening a YAML file from xdg-open works, but IntelliJ is not using xdg-open.

I suppose this could be related to the fact that I initially installed plain Ubuntu and then switched it to Kubuntu by installing the KDE packages. I'm using Oracle JDK 6.

Answer (score 3):

To edit them as plain text files in IDEA, I can go to Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S), search for File Types and choose "Files opened in associated applications", then remove .yml from the list. Then double-click a YAML file and choose to edit it as a text file. But this is not ideal - I'd like to be able to use associated external applications.